# TypeError: res.partner(id,) is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9

I have a button on the sale.order.line model that opens a popup on the stock.picking model. The popup opens perfectly , but when I want to spend some fields default to popup, Odoo displays the following message:

**TypeError: res.partner(id,) is not JSON serializable**

In the following images shown how the popup:

[image]

[image]

This is the function that opens the popup:

```
    @api.multi
    def action_stock_picking(self):        
        self.ensure_one()
        picking_form = self.env.ref('stock.view_picking_form', False)
            return {
                'name': _('Formulario de Inventario: Recepciones'),
                'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
                'view_type': 'form',
                'view_mode': 'form',
                'res_model': 'stock.picking',
                'views': [(picking_form.id, 'form')],
                'view_id': picking_form.id,
                'target': 'new',
                'context': dict(
          #partner_id stock.picking = partner_id sale.order.line

                    **default_partner_id=self.order_id.partner_id,**

                    default_origin=self.order_id.name,
                    default_picking_type_id = 1,
                    default_model='stock.picking',
                    default_res_id=self.id,
                    default_composition_mode='comment',
                    mark_invoice_as_sent=True,
                ),
            }
```

When I want to spend the client popup, Odoo shows the error that I mentioned previously.

Thank you very much to all. I hope some help from you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set default_partner_id like **default_partner_id=self.order_id.partner_id.id,** instead of **default_partner_id=self.order_id.partner_id,** to set default partner in picking. Please use below code.

```
@api.multi
def action_stock_picking(self):        
    self.ensure_one()
    picking_form = self.env.ref('stock.view_picking_form', False)
        return {
            'name': _('Formulario de Inventario: Recepciones'),
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'view_type': 'form',
            'view_mode': 'form',
            'res_model': 'stock.picking',
            'views': [(picking_form.id, 'form')],
            'view_id': picking_form.id,
            'target': 'new',
            'context': dict(
      #partner_id stock.picking = partner_id sale.order.line

                default_partner_id=self.order_id.partner_id.id,

                default_origin=self.order_id.name,
                default_picking_type_id = 1,
                default_model='stock.picking',
                default_res_id=self.id,
                default_composition_mode='comment',
                mark_invoice_as_sent=True,
            ),
        }
```